# Can’t see my shared resources from my server in a client computer, connected through a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv4, sharing

I’m new to networking. I am the new network manager in a business. A few days ago I tried to change a computer in a branch office to a new one, but I can´t get the server to see that new client.

When I try `net view <VPN IPv4 client address>` from server, I get error 53.
From what I know (since I'm new, I think this is correct information):

- VPN is stablished through RRAS.
- VPN in client connects and can ping from server to `<VPN IPv4 client address>` client.
- Can successfully `net view <VPN IPv4 server address>`. I get no errors and can see resources.
- I am using 2 DNS servers.
- Unchecked in VPN settings, IPv4 properties: *use default gateway on the remote network*.

I repeat, the server was already configured and old computers connected to this server are working correctly and I can `net view` them.

Comment: Maybe your server recognizes computers by their MAC address? Or the firewall blocks this MAC address...

Comment: Hello zx485, thank you for your answer. It could be. Do you know how can I check that?

Comment: You have to check this in your server configurations of DHCP, DNS and `iptables` services.